# Modify start_index of list at runtime python

Tags: python, list, element, skip

I was wondering if it is possible to modify the value of the start_index of a list while iterating trough it.

What I've noticed so far is that the code

```py
index = 0
l = ['1','2','3']
for elem in l[index:]:
    print(elem, index)
```

always prints out the value 0 while iterating trough the loop.

I tried to modify the value inside the loop like this:

```py
for elem in l[index:]:
    print(elem, index)
    index = index+1
```

and the value of the index is printed out correctly but I can see again every element of the list.
I was trying to skip elements of the list based on some other calculations (it's not just hoping 1 element, in fact i can't use the form

```py
l[start_index:end_index:count]
```

because count can be different through every iteration, this is why I need to set it by myself.)

Is it to possible to achieve something like that?
Thank you

Comment: it gets value from `index` at start and later it doesn't use varible `index` - so there is no sense to change it. For some objects you can use `next(object)` to skip element - ie. when you get lines from file.  `for line in file: next(file)`. For some you may use `iter()` to create iterator and then you  can also use `next()` but you may need try/except to catch error when you try to use next() on last element and there is no next element.

Comment: if you want ot change `index` then maybe you should use `while True` and manually change `index += 1` and `index += more`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, if you are jumping around in your iteration, based on some calculation, you might want:

```
L = [...]
i = 0
while i is not None:
    do_something_with(L[i])
    i = my_calculation(i)
```

So the basic idea here is -- you are using L as your list of data, i as your index into the data, and then when my_calculation returns None (rather than the next index, ...), you exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for "[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)."

For example:

```
print(list(enumerate(["apples", "and", "oranges"])))
```

...outputs:

```
[(0, 'apples'), (1, 'and'), (2, 'oranges')]
```

And then if you want to start counting at, say, 10, it has a parameter that lets you do that:

```
print(list(enumerate(["apples", "and", "oranges"], 10)))
```

outputs:

```
[(10, 'apples'), (11, 'and'), (12, 'oranges')]
```

Answer (score 0):

For some objects you can use `next()` to skip element

```
f = open("filename.txt")

# skip two lines before loop
next(f)
next(f)

for line in f:
    print(line)
    # skip one line in loop
    next(f)
```

but you may have to use `try/except` to catch error StopIteration when you use `next() on last element and there is no next element

```
try:

    # skip two lines before loop
    next(f)
    next(f)

    for line in f:
        print(line)
        # skip one line in every loop
        next(f)

except StopIteration:
    pass
```

For some objects you can use `iter()` to create iterator and then you can use `next()` to skip items.

```
index = 0

l = ['1','2','3','4','5']
it = iter(l[index:])

try:

    for item in it:
        print(item)
        # skip two items in every loop
        next(it)
        next(it)

except StopIteration:
    pass
```

You can use `for` loop and `if/else` to skip more elements

```
index = 0

l = ['1','2','3','4','5']
it = iter(l[index:])

try:

    for item in it:
        print(item)
        if some_condition:
            # skip two items 
            for _ in range(2):
                next(it) 

except StopIteration:
    pass
```

---

But it may be easier to use `while True` or `while index < ...` and manually change `index` and use it to get values.

Or use `enumerate` with `if index condition: continue` to skip loop for some indexes.

Comment: Yeah I think the ```while True``` form is maybe the easier to implement..